# Вывод файлов в консоли

Tags: c#, консоль

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
 FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
 if (fi.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-Day))
 {
  Console.WriteLine(fi)                        
 }
}
```

Есть цикл, который перебирает все файлы и должен вывести только определенные, но он выводит абсолютно все, что нужно исправить в Console.WriteLine ?

Comment: Чему равен Day? Приведите также пример входных данных.

Comment: @Anamnian Day = 10

Comment: Что там в итоге стоит-то ``(-Day)`` или ``(Day)``?

Comment: "вывести только определенные" Какие файлы вы считаете определенными?

Comment: @Эникейщик (-Day)

Comment: @Anamnian те которые будут старше 10 моих дней

Comment: Не вижу в этом коде определения "старше 10 моих дней", вижу только "старше 10 дней, начиная с текущего дня".

Comment: @Anamnian оговорился, это я и имел ввиду что старше 10 дней начиная с текущего дня.

Comment: Сейчас код по поведению напоминает тот что вы ожидаете. Если это не так — проверьте еще раз выходные данные.

Answer (score 1):

> что нужно исправить в `Console.WriteLine`?

Тут нечего исправлять в `Console.WriteLine`, т.к.:

> Свойство FileSystemInfo.LastWriteTime
>
> Получает или задает время последней операции записи в текущий файл или
>   каталог.

Вы это сравниваете с текущим значением даты + 10 дней (`DateTime.Now.AddDays(Day)`). Соответственно, так как у нас файлы не писались в будущем, цикл обработает все файлы.

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что вы берете текущее время и прибавляете к нему N-дней.

В комментарии вы написали 10. Все файлы будут подходить под это условие.

Если вы хотите вывести файлы, которые были записаны раньше, чем 10 дней назад, то вам нужно выполнять вычитание.

В общем, проблема в вашем if.